# Create Mac min M1 support build using electron packager

Tags: electron, electron-packager, macos-big-sur, apple-silicon, apple-m1

I want to create a electron build for Mac Mini M1 support but the build process taking so much of time to generate a webpack build.It takes around 5-6 hours and still showing me only 14%

Can anyone help out from this issue.I have attached a screen shot below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a python issue. Try to install python version 3.8 or greater and nodeJS version 14.15.3 or greater.

Compile your custom addons again with using electron-rebuild command like this

electron-rebuild --arch=arm64

Then create a build it will definitely working.